# How to pass reference to current class to a function within the same class

Tags: vba, excel

Say if I have a class called `State` and there is a function `Function Outer(stateCopy As State)` and there is a function inside `State` class: `Function Inner()`. Function `Inner()` makes use of `Outer()`, it should pass it the reference on an object of this class, but how could one do that?

In other programming languages there are links to the same class, like `this` in Java. Is there something like this in Excel vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a running instance of a class you can refer to that instance as "Me"
 so

```
Outer(Me)
```

is valid. Is that what you wanted?